# When should you leave a comment with a VTC?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52111/could-saturns-rings-be-removed) received -4 points and 4 VTCs at the time of this writing. As DW pointed out, none of the 4 left any reason for the VTC.

Do we have an official policy on when a comment explaining a VTC should happen? Should everyone who VTC leave a comment? Is it ever appropriate for a question to receive the full 5 VTCs without any comments explaining why?

Comment: You should always leave a comment with a VTC as discussed here: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/reminder-to-close-voters

Comment: I find it strange that duplicate VTCs make a comment for you, but none of the other ones do.

Comment: I'm one of the four who downvoted the question, but I did leave reason in the form of an answer – which was accepted by the asker.

Comment: @rek that's not the same thing. The comment is made for them to improve their question.  So that they can get a suitable question, which would not need to be downvoted. An answer does none of that. Even worse, it tends to reinforce the idea that their question is good, "cause they have good answers".

Comment: I almost always leave a comment before I VTC. That said, there are definitely exceptions, and I sometimes don't comment on questions by users that should be able to figure out what is acceptable. Unless they ask me.